# R Shiny Filter with CheckboxInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have trouble to filter my data set in my Shiny Application based on a CheckBoxInput.

I guess the problem is the wrong formatting of the CheckboxInput.

Here, I also have a exemplary code:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:20,ncol=2))
colnames(x) <- c("Test1","Test2")

ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput("icons", "Choose icons:", choices = 1:10),
textOutput("test"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$test <- renderText({
  req(input$icons)
  tmp_input <- as.numeric(as.vector(input$icons))
  tmp <- x %>%
    dplyr::filter(Test1 %in% tmp_input)
  return(tmp)
})
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error message is : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp` is a data.frame (and actually also a list). You return this to get it rendered by `renderText`, which uses `cat`. But `cat` expects atomic vectors and can't handle lists. Try the combination of `renderPrint` and `verbatimTextOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:20,ncol=2))
colnames(x) <- c("Test1","Test2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("icons", "Choose icons:", choices = 1:10),
  verbatimTextOutput("test"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    req(input$icons)
    tmp_input <- as.numeric(as.vector(input$icons))
    tmp <- x %>%
      dplyr::filter(Test1 %in% tmp_input)
    return(tmp)
  })
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```